# I can't create forms in TYPO3

Tags: forms, configuration, typo3

In the Form section of the backend side of the TYPO3 platform, it shows the following message when trying to create a new form
No accessible form storage folders
I have done an investigation and have not been able to solve it.

Conduct an investigation to find details about that message.

Comment: Do you have included TypoScript sets? https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/QuickStartForIntegrators/Index.html

Comment: what is the error message? try to format your text or include/link to a screenshot, which will show some context.